# Kotlin explicit vs implicit get() and set()

Tags: kotlin, getter-setter, getter

What are the reason why we use or explicitly use `get()` and `set()` in Kotlin? I have a model that is throwing an error when I remove explicit `get()` in its variable declaration.

```
data class SampleDomain(
    val publishTime: String = ""
) {

    // Removing get() here, publishTime becomes empty
    val formattedDate: String
        get() = LocalDate.parse(publishTime, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME).format(
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM. dd, yyyy")
        )

}
```

Comment: Can you include the code where you instantiate SampleDomain and where you try to access formattedDate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`get()` and `set()` is how we define getters and setters in Kotlin. So simply answering why do we use them is because they are required to define a getter/setter.

If you mean the difference between the following definitions:

```kotlin
val formattedDate: String = acquireDate()
val formattedDate: String get() = acquireDate()
```

Then `get()` is not here just to be more explicit. These two code fragments do much different things. The first acquires the date during the object initialization, stores it inside a field and the getter returns this stored value. The second defines a custom getter, but the value is not stored anywhere - the date is acquired again and again every time the getter is invoked.

See the documentation for more info: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#getters-and-setters

Comment: Does it mean that the second one with explicit getter will only get executed whenever you use/call it somewhere and not during initialization? That will make sense since the raw date is coming from API and is empty by default. But if we say during initialization, it became a little confusing since there is always a value being provided when initializing the sample data class. Maybe because of setting its default value to `""`?

Comment: @BitwiseDEVS the getter is only executed when something "gets" the value. Nothing would need to "get" the value during initialization surely? Only set it.

Comment: @BitwiseDEVS Yes, exactly. `get()` is executed whenever you access `formattedDate` property. Without `get()` the code is executed only once, when the object is being initialized.

Answer (score 2):

As broot says, adding `get()` changes the meaning very significantly.

Without the `get()`, you're declaring a property with an initial value. For example:

```
class SomeClass {
    var prop = initialisingFunction()
}
```

That's roughly equivalent to:

```
class SomeClass {
    var prop: Int

    init {
        prop = initialisingFunction()
    }
}
```

So `initialisingFunction()` is called only once, during construction, and the class stores its value in a [backing field](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#backing-fields) after that. If the property is a `var`, as here, then the value can be changed after that.

---

But *with* the `get()`, you're declaring a property with a custom [getter](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#getters-and-setters):

```
class SomeClass {
    val prop
        get() = initialisingFunction()
}
```

That's even more roughly equivalent to:

```
class SomeClass {
    fun getProp() = initialisingFunction()
}
```

Here, there's *no* backing field to store the property; *every* time you get its value, it will call `initialisingFunction()` and hand you that value directly.

If the property is a `var`, then you'll also need a custom setter. (Otherwise, the default one would cause a backing field to be created, which it would set, but whose value you'd never see…)

---

Which version to use will depend on your needs. If the property needs to change in line with something external, then a custom getter is probably needed. It can also be a slightly memory saving if you need to return a value that's the same for all instance of the class. But if calculating the value is expensive, and/or if it's different for each instance, especially if it needs to be mutable, then you'll probably need a property with an initialiser.

Answer (score 1):

1. **get()**

You can define custom accessors for a property. If you define a custom getter, it will be called every time you access the property (this way you can implement a computed property). Here's an example of a custom getter:

```
class Recangle(
    var width: Int = 10,
    var height: Int = 20
) {
    val area: Int get() = width * height
    
    init {
        println("old area: $area") // 10 * 20 = 200

        width = 20
        println("new area: $area") // 20 * 20 = 400
    }
}
```

So with custom getter, every time we call `area`, width * height will be calculated again, let's see what will happen without custom getter:

```
class Recangle(
    var width: Int = 10,
    var height: Int = 20
) {
    val area: Int = width * height // 10 * 20 = 200
    
    init {
        println("old area: $area") // 200

        width = 20
        println("new area: $area") // 200
    }
}
```

Without a custom getter we will get the same result every  time we call area, even if the width and the height are changed, so the area we be calculated only the first time and stay the same.

2. **set()**

If you define a custom setter, it will be called every time you assign a value to the property, except its initialization. A custom setter looks like this:

```
class Recangle() {
    var area: Int = 0
        set(value) {
            val areaValue = value / 1000 // make custom operations
            updateArea(areaValue) // use value in other functions
            field = value // update the field value
        }
        
    fun updateArea(area: Int) {}
}
```

Also you can make setter private:

```
var area: Int = 100
    private set // the setter is private and has the default implementation
```